# How Spark read distributed files

Tags: apache-spark, fasta

Fasta file is a multi line file. It structured like

```
>ID_1
ACGTAGCATGC
>ID_2
AGCTAGTACATC
```

So to get the sequences, I have to read 1 line out of 2.

I have mutliple big fasta files (120Go per file) to read. I use spark to read these files. I currently use this to get all sequences on a dataframe:

```scala
val sequences = sc.textFile("path/to/directory").sliding(2, 2).map{case Array(id, seq) => seq}
```

Does this command allow to get all sequences knowing that the files are distributed on the spark cluster ?

Comment: have you tried it?

Comment: if "path/to/directory" is a distribute file system, there is a good chance that all your data will be loaded to Spark RDD (not Dataframe)

Comment: If you want to read fasta and other genomics files in spark you might want to checkout [hadoop-bam](https://github.com/HadoopGenomics/Hadoop-BAM/) which is a library that has file formats for reading fasta, bam, vcf, etc.  Fasta is a pretty simple format, but things like BAM are pretty complicated to deal with.  (disclaimer, I contribute to hadoop-bam)

Comment: Yes i try it. (https://github.com/xgaia/DSparK). I try a count on `sequences` and it return the right number of sequence on a single file, but the number is wrong on multiple files

Answer (score 2):

You can try using FASTdoop (https://github.com/umbfer/fastdoop), in which are implemented readers for FASTA and FASTQ files.

This is an example of code:

```java
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").appName("FASTdoop Test Short").getOrCreate();    
SparkContext sc = spark.sparkContext();
JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(sc);

Configuration inputConf = jsc.hadoopConfiguration();
inputConf.setInt("look_ahead_buffer_size", 4096);
String inputPath = "data/short.fasta";

JavaPairRDD<Text, Record> dSequences2 = jsc.newAPIHadoopFile(inputPath, 
        FASTAshortInputFileFormat.class, Text.class, Record.class, inputConf);

/* We drop the keys of the new RDD since they are not used */
JavaRDD<Record> dSequences = dSequences2.values();

for (Record sequence : dSequences.collect()) {
    System.out.println("ID: " + sequence.getKey());
    System.out.println("Sequence: " + sequence.getValue());
}
```

You can find more details inside the README file of the 'spark_support' branch.

Answer (score 1):

Since every record starts with '>', you could try changing the line delimiter to '>' ('\n' by default) with this line of code:

```scala
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("textinputformat.record.delimiter",">")
```

Then this should do the trick for you:

```scala
sc.textFile("...")
    .filter(_ != "")
    .map(_.split("\n")(1))
```

Note that the filter is only there to get rid of the first empty record that gets generated because the file starts with '>'.

Comment: Can I do this for a single file? I want to be able to read other files that don't have the same record delimiter.

Also, the following worked for me: `sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("textinputformat.record.delimiter",">")`
Just noting if anyone's having trouble.